# wordpress plugin custom activation message

Tags: php, wordpress

i created a wordpress plugin .when i activated the plugin i got `"plugin activated"` flash msg. actually i want to customize this message to `"connect to my-plugin"` and also provide a link to this plugin settings page. i try

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'your_custom_function' );

function your_custom_function() {

   echo "connect to my-plugin";

    if( $error ) {
        // Put everything here
    }

}
```

results connect to my-plugin msg shown on every page in admin panel.i just want to show my custom msg only at the time of activation on plugins page only
also i got an error
The plugin generated 2 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice `“headers already sent”` messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the one filter hook you are looking for is [plugin_action_links_(plugin_file_name)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/plugin_action_links_(plugin_file_name)) which allows you to add custom links to your plugin entry on the Plugins page.

To display an activation message, see [this tutorial](https://tommcfarlin.com/plugin-activation-message/).

You could have found these two with some research on your own.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was researching how to do this and your response has helped me almost 3 years later 